# To Read connection String from web.config

Tags: wcf, web-config

WCF service on IIS.
I have got a problem with reading connection string from web.config file.
my connection string looks like this :

```
    <connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="ABC" 
    connectionString="DEF"
    providerName="GGG"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

My code in Global.asax.cs :

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                    

           cons_Webdata =  WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC"].ConnectionString;

        }
```

I have error message in "cons_Webdata = ......." :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using ConfigurationManager instead of WebConfigurationManager

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                    
    cons_Webdata =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Otherwise, use the code sample from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

```
        System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
            System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
        if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
        {
            connString =
                rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
            if (connString != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"",
                    connString.ConnectionString);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
        }
```

Comment: What is "MyWebsiteRoot"?

Comment: The root directory of your IIS website

Answer (score 1):

Check out on how to use WebConfigurationManager in web application [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx). You need to read the section connection strings from the config file and then use them as shown below:

```
           // Get the connectionStrings section.
            ConnectionStringsSection connectionStringsSection =
                WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("connectionStrings")
                as ConnectionStringsSection;

            // Get the connectionStrings key,value pairs collection.
            ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStrings =
                connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings;

            // Get the collection enumerator.
            IEnumerator connectionStringsEnum =
                connectionStrings.GetEnumerator();

            // Loop through the collection and 
            // display the connectionStrings key, value pairs.
            int i = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("[Display the connectionStrings]");
            while (connectionStringsEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                string name = connectionStrings[i].Name;
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Value: {1}",
                name, connectionStrings[name]);
                i += 1;
            }
```